# array.length and empty function is not helping me

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have three checkboxes with common name

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkBox[]" id="checkBox" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkBox[]" id="checkBox" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkBox[]" id="checkBox" value="3">
```

And jquery to push the selected checkbox value into an array before I pass that array to ajax

```
var data = {'checkBox[]': []};
$(":checked").each(function () 
{
    data['checkBox[]'].push($(this).val());
});
```

I am able to iterate through the checkBox array in PHP in the Ajax page but failing on the client side.

**checkBox.length** is not giving me the number of checkboxes I've checked. I am unable to find out whether an array is an **empty** array.
I have tried - **if (checkBox === undefined || checkBox.length == 0)** but got no result. How can I find the length for the above array and whether it is an **empty** array. I do not want to pass an empty array to the ajax url.

Comment: Note on your HTML: Your checkboxes should have different `id` values, or just omit the `id`. Ids are supposed to be unique across a page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unclear what you are looking for, but to get length of array you are building inside `data` object use:

```
var len = data['checkBox[]'].length;
```

Note: as currently shown in you sample code `data` is object with one property named `"checkbox[]"` with array as value, possibly you were looking for something else, maybe `data = {checkbox:[]}` or just `checkbox=[]`;

Comment: Working like charm. Thank you really so much. var len = data['checkBox[]'].length gives me the total number of checkbox I've checked in the form. Thank you really so much :)

Answer (score 1):

change your code into this

```
var checkBox = [];
$("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
checkBox.push($(this).val());
});

console.log(checkBox.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is really unclear.  If you are looking to get a count of the number of checkboxes you have checked you can try
    `$('checkbox[name="checkbox[]"]:checked').length;`

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
data['checkBox[]'] = $('input[name="checkBox[]"]:checked').map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
});
```